# How can I add body to JavaScript section?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new Javascript learner. This code had grabbed my interest. How can I remove what is inside the  sections and add it to the  sections. In other words, I want it to be a full Javascript code. Can anyone please lead or teach me to the right path or give me an example of how the code is going to look like. Thanks

Body:

```
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demoNew"></p>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var n = parseInt(prompt("How many numbers will be entered(max 20)-"));
    var numArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        numArray[i]=parseInt(prompt("Enter number between 10 and 100 "));
    }
    var uniqueNum = [...new Set(numArray)];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Count of items entered: "+n;
    document.getElementById("demoNew").innerHTML = "Numbers-dduplicates removed: "+uniqueNum;
</script>
```

Comment: "How can I remove what is inside the sections and add it to the sections."
So you want to put the HTML codes into the javascript? Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like getting 1~20 inputs between integer 10 and 100 from prompt and make a set with them but you want this without HTML.

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.setAttribute("id", "demo");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(p);
p = document.createElement("p");
p.setAttribute("id", "demoNew");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(p);
//create element and append to body as a child

var n = -1;
while(n<1 || n>20) {
  n = parseInt(prompt("How many numbers will be entered(between 1 and 20)"));
}
var numArray = [];
var input = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    input = parseInt(prompt("Enter #"+(i+1)+" number between 10 and 100 "));
    if(input>=10 && input<=100) {
      numArray.push(input);
    }
    else {
      alert("invalid input");
      i--;
    }
}
var uniqueNumArray = new Set(numArray);
console.log(uniqueNumArray.size);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Count of items entered: "+n;
document.getElementById("demoNew").innerHTML = "Numbers-duplicates removed: "+Array.from(uniqueNumArray);
```